# Why does angular sets timeout for directive when it has ngModel?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have an isolated scope directive with a test, but without adding any code it does not pass

> $timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks();

directive code:

```
angular.module('testModu', [])

.directive('testDir', [function() {
  return {
    scope: {
    }
  };
}]);
```

test code:

```
describe('test directive', function() {
  var $httpBackend, $timeout, $rootScope, scope, element, inputElement;

  beforeEach(module('testModu'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_, _$timeout_, $compile) {
    $timeout = _$timeout_;

    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;

    element = $compile('<div test-dir ng-model="amod"></div>')($rootScope);

    scope = element.isolateScope();
  }));

    it('shows the following: Deferred tasks to flush', function() {
      $timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks();
    });
});
```

test results:

```
Error: Deferred tasks to flush (1): {id: 0, time: 0}
```

but when I remove the **ng-model** from the element then it passes the test without any deferred tasks.

Comment: why wouldn't it have a pending task? after the element is compiled, the variable assigned to that `ng-model` has to be checked in a new digest loop....

Comment: so I should put `$timeout.flush();` at the start of the test?

Comment: well, it's not really clear what you are trying to test here; and no, putting `$timeout.flush()` before the call to `$compile` wouldn't make it not necessary to process another `$digest` after the compile.

Comment: I mean put it at the start of `it`

Comment: then the only thing that would be testing is if `$timeout.flush()` works or not.  again, it's not really clear what you expect this test to be telling you here.

Comment: you should be testing that you are receiving the correct HTML in your markup, not testing an angular function...